# The second file isn't uploading to FTP server [node.js + multer]

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, multer

I have problem with uploading a images to my FTP server. The problem is that the first array of photos that I'm uploading is uploaded successfully but second time If I'm trying to upload something it isn't working and I don't know why. To uploading files I'm using multer-sftp package.

Code:

```
const storage = sftpStorage({
    sftp: {
        host: process.env.FTP_HOST,
        user: process.env.FTP_USER,
        password: process.env.FTP_PASSWORD,
        port: 22,
    },
    destination: (req: any, file: any, callback: any) => {
        callback(null, "");
    },
    filename: (req: any, file: any, callback: any) => {
        callback(null, `${Date.now()}-${file.originalname}`);
    },
});

const fileFilter = (
    req: Request,
    file: Express.Multer.File,
    cb: FileFilterCallback
) => {
    if (
        file.mimetype === "image/png" ||
        file.mimetype === "image/jpg" ||
        file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" ||
        file.mimetype === "image/webp"
    ) {
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb(null, false);
    }
};
    app.use(
    multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: fileFilter }).array("images", 8)
);
```

Comment: second array = second HTTP request?

Comment: Yes. When I'm sending second request It is problem with uploading